# Android Shared Preference - Delete a Single Item

Tags: android, listview, button, methods, sharedpreferences

First off - any tips/help are appreciated.

For the question - i am creating an app that keeps adds locations to a shared preference file (along with location name and date). These locations are saved as location logs and are displayed to the user in a List View. The user can click on anyone of the location and they will be passed on to the selected items details page, here they can either change the name of the location, navigate to the location or even delete the location.

The problem is that when the user deletes a location the Shared preferences file is properly updated but the program crashes. I have no idea why it does that, i tried doing debugging using Toasts, but that didn't work so well.

I have attached the java code that handles the single item description view. The part that handles the delete function is the "onClickDelete" method. There is something wrong there.

P.S - i tried using editor.commit() and editor.apply(), both still didn't stop the program from crashing.

```
   package com.android.ict.seneca.androidpocketguide;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

public class Websites extends Activity
        implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    private final String CLASS_NAME = "Websites";
    private int request_Code = 1;
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy, HH:mm");
    String date;
    String location;
    String name;
    String favourite;
    int counter;
    List listName;
    ImageView image1;
    ImageView image2;
    String [] favo = new String [100];
    String [] unfavo = new String [100];
    int c1 = 0;
    int c2 = 0;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    private SharedPreferences savedState;

    private ListView listView;
    private List<RowItem> rowItems;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_websites);
        listName= new ArrayList();
        String app_name = "//sdcard//LocoLog.txt";
        //int counter = 0, flag = 0;
        String temp = "";
        savedState = getSharedPreferences( "quantitySaved", MODE_PRIVATE );
        editor = savedState.edit();
        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        counter = savedState.getInt("counter", -1 );

        //Toast.makeText(this,"Websites: " + counter,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(counter!=-1)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= counter; i++) {
                String na;
                String da;
                String lo;
                String fa;
                na = "name" + i;
                da = "date" + i;
                lo = "location" + i;
                fa = "favourite" + i;

                name = savedState.getString(na, "na");
                //name = "Name: " + name;
                date = savedState.getString(da, "da");
                //date = "Date: " + date;
                location = savedState.getString(lo, "lo");
                //location = "Location: " + location;
                favourite = savedState.getString(fa, "fa");

                //Toast.makeText(this, "name: " + name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if(favourite.equals("Yes"))
                {
                    favo[c1] = name + "]" + location + "]" + date + "]" + favourite + "]" + counter;
                    //Toast.makeText(this, "favo[" + c1 + "]: " + favo[c1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    c1++;
                }
                else if(favourite.equals("No"))
                {
                    unfavo[c2] = name + "]" + location + "]" + date + "]" + favourite + "]" + counter;
                    //Toast.makeText(this, "unfavo[" + c2 + "]: " + unfavo[c2], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    c2++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR: Favourite value is wrong!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


                //Toast.makeText(this, "The data: "+name + " " + location + " " + date,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //listName.add(new RowItem(name, location, date, counter));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No locations saved yet",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        int co;
        String[] separated1 = new String[5];
        String[] separated2 = new String[5];

        for(int i = 0; i < c1; i++)
        {
            separated1 = favo[i].split("]");
            co =  Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(separated1[4]));
            Toast.makeText(this, "name: " + separated1[0] + " location: " + separated1[1] + " date: " + separated1[2] + " favourite: " + separated1[3] + " counter: " +separated1[4]  ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            listName.add(new RowItem(separated1[0], separated1[1], separated1[2], separated1[3], co));
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < c2; i++)
        {
            separated2 = unfavo[i].split("]");
            co =  Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(separated1[4]));
            Toast.makeText(this, "name: " + separated2[0] + " location: " + separated2[1] + " date: " + separated2[2] + " favourite: " + separated2[3] + " counter: " + separated1[4],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            listName.add(new RowItem(separated2[0], separated2[1], separated2[2], separated2[3], co));
        }

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.locationList);

        //image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
        //image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);

        listView.setAdapter( new CustomListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, listName ) );
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String s = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), SingleListItem.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("product", s);
        String p = String.valueOf(position); //convert position from int to String
        myIntent.putExtra("position", p);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    public void onClickDelete(View view)
    {
        editor.clear().commit();
        //String cities = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
        Toast.makeText(this, "All Locations Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,Websites.class ),request_Code);

        //rowItems.remove(position);
    }

    public void onClickHome(View view)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Home button pressed ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class ),request_Code);

    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "onStart invoked!");
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "onPause invoked!!");
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "onResume invoked!!");
    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "onStop invoked!!!");
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "onDestroy INVOKED!!!");
    }

    public void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "onRestart invoked!!");
    }

}
```

The Stack: (This points to this line: counter = savedState.getInt("counter", -1 );

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.android.ict.seneca.androidpocketguide, PID: 6739
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.ict.seneca.androidpocketguide/com.android.ict.seneca.androidpocketguide.Websites}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
                      at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:242)
                      at com.android.ict.seneca.androidpocketguide.Websites.onCreate(Websites.java:78)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Have you defined `Websites` in your manifest?

Comment: Yes, <activity
        android:label="Websites"
        android:name="com.android.ict.seneca.androidpocketguide.Websites" >

Comment: Could you post your stacktrace?

Comment: your problem is : `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`

Comment: @MarkKeen yes, i realize that. But it is giving that error on this line : counter = savedState.getInt("counter", -1 ); There is nothing such going on over here.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling, and trying a fresh install? my guess is that when you place "counter" key and some value into `SharedPreferences` it is as a `String` not an `int` - uninstall/fresh install will set to default, if it works, then thats probably the issue - I can't see where "counter" is put into SharedPreferences`.

Comment: @MarkKeen yup that was it. I did store the counter as String. Thank you so much for helping me out!